# Remove the "This is the format of your plot grid:" in a plotly subplot in a Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, plotly

When using Plotly in a Jupyter Notebook plotting an offline iplot figure with subplots, before the figure I get the output:

```
This is the format of your plot grid: 
[ (1,1) x1,y1 ]    [ (1,2) x2,y2 ]    [ (1,3) x3,y3 ]    [ (1,4) x4,y4 ]  
[ (2,1) x5,y5 ]    [ (2,2) x6,y6 ]    [ (2,3) x7,y7 ]    [ (2,4) x8,y8 ]  
[ (3,1) x9,y9 ]    [ (3,2) x10,y10 ]  [ (3,3) x11,y11 ]  [ (3,4) x12,y12 ]
[ (4,1) x13,y13 ]  [ (4,2) x14,y14 ]  [ (4,3) x15,y15 ]  [ (4,4) x16,y16 ]
```

How do I remove this from the output?

Example code:

```
import plotly as pl
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

fig = pl.tools.make_subplots(cols=4, rows=4)

for col in range(1, 5):
    for row in range(1, 5):
        x = np.random.rand(500)
        trace = go.Histogram(x=x, histnorm='density')
        fig.append_trace(trace, row, col)

pl.offline.iplot(fig)
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Figured it out, set the `print_grid` parameter to False:

```
fig = pl.tools.make_subplots(cols=4, rows=4, print_grid=False)
```

Which I found in

```
help(pl.tools.make_subplots)
```